docker rmi <image:tag> deletes both amd64 and arm64 builds on Apple Silicon
I have an image built for both linux/amd64, and linux/arm64 on my system. I wish to delete only one of the builds and keep the other, however docker rmi deletes both of them.
I tried the following:

Running docker rmi within an x86 shell (that was launched as arch -x86_64 $SHELL)
Running docker with the flag DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64 in both x86 shell and arm shell.

Neither worked, what gives? Is this even possible?
I am using Apple M3 (tagging apple-m1 for wider reach) Sonoma 14.4, with Docker version version 25.0.3, build 4debf41.
